# How to implement an OptionMenu in an Activity

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I tried to implement [this](http://adnan.chohdry.com/android/android-how-to-implement-option-menu-in-activity-or-dialog/), without succes.

The menu Buttons aren't showing.
What's wrong with my code?

My menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/lblActMenuSave"
    android:icon="@mipmap/diskette_128"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Kaydet"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/lblActMenuPic"
    android:icon="@mipmap/photography_128"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Yenile"/>
</menu>
```

And how I call it in my Activiy

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.kayitdetay,menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.lblActMenuSave:

            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
        case R.id.lblActMenuPic:
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent5);

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not able to see the menu buttons or the menu itself is not displayed ??

Comment: @srv_sud menu itselft not displayed

Comment: @srv_sud onCreateOptions menu not calling

Comment: I think i need to call something on onCreate ? ın fragments i do setHasOptionsMenu(true); but not work in activity.

Comment: you mean menu button is visible in Actionbar and when you launch the activity onCreateOptions menu is not called??

Comment: nope. I mean nothing showing in actionbar, no buttons

Comment: the link which you mentioned in your question, I hope you are using the activity example from that, not the Dialog example.

Comment: yea dude, using for activty one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109573/discussion-between-srv-sud-and-keikoman).

Answer (score 1):

Change in design xml

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

i think you want to show menu icon always..

Answer (score 0):

You should return true in your onCreateOptionsMenu function

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.kayitdetay,menu);
    return true;
}
```

and return true in onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.lblActMenuSave:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            return true;

        case R.id.lblActMenuPic:
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent5);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try this??

Comment: This is code taken from my app adjusted to @keikoman question.

Comment: still menu buttons  not showing @GrzegorzBielański